# localStorage results in function being loaded infinite times

Tags: javascript, function, window.location

I am filtering what users see based on a selected value. Users can choose between consumer and commercial with the code supposed to be adding "/commercial" to the URL of commercial users and "/consumer" being added to the URL of consumer users.

This is the current code I am using, which results in the below functions being run every time the page is loaded, resulting in an infinite loop.

```
/* Hides non-commercial products */
function commercial() {
  window.location.assign(window.location.origin  + "/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/commercial");
 localStorage.setItem("saved", "0");
}
/* Hides non-consumer products */
function consumer() {
  window.location.assign(window.location.origin + "/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/consumer");
  localStorage.setItem("saved", "1");
}
/* Shows all products */
function reset() {
  window.location.assign(window.location.origin + "/collections/{{ collection.handle }}");
  localStorage.removeItem("saved");
}
```

**UPDATED CODE:** LocalStorage results in the above functions being run every time the page is loaded, resulting in an infinite loop. Below is mt LocalStorage get the saved value of the key code:

```
    /* Remember last clicked button and store it in LocalStorage */
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  const value = localStorage.getItem("saved");
  if (value == "0") {
    commercial();
  } else if (value == "1") {
    consumer()
  } else {
    reset()
  }
});
```

This is what the code outputs: (DJI is just an example of a collection)

```
saved == "0" outputs /collections/dji/commercial
saved == "1" outputs /collections/dji/consumer
saved == "2" outputs /collections/dji/
```

Comment: where are these functions run? Do you check localstorage before running the functions?

Comment: @FredStark, the functions are run onclick of a specific button. LocalStorage is checked before and overwritten by the same button click.

Comment: @Ravikumar Thanks, I've got it to display the correct URL now but it is now stuck in an infinite loop resulting in the page to continue to be relaoded.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` holds the complete URL thus it's appending to previous URL, instead use `window.location.origin`.

```
window.location.assign(window.location.origin  + "/commercial");
```

Comment: This is what I have done. It needs the /collections part as that comes before it. `/* Hides non-commercial products */
function commercial() {
  window.location.assign(window.location.origin  + "/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/commercial");
  localStorage.setItem("saved", "0");
}
/* Hides non-consumer products */
function consumer() {
  window.location.assign(window.location.origin + "/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/consumer");
  localStorage.setItem("saved", "1");
}`

Comment: what do you mean? can you elaborate it please?

Comment: Ok, so once I go to a page with the function on it it will take me to the correct URL but the function will continue to take me to the page even though I'm already on it, resulting in it to be reloaded

Comment: how did you parse this `window.location.origin  + "/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/commercial"`?  do you mean `\`${window.location.origin}/collections/${collection.handle}/commercial\``

Comment: other than onclick, are you calling these methods anywhere?

Comment: also make sure to add type to button element `<buttton type="button">` otherwise it'll behave like submit if it's inside a form element.

Comment: The {{ collection.handle }} comes from Shopify and is used to get the current collection's name

Comment: I have localstorage bringing them back in which might be calling them everytime the page loads?

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the issue. LocalStorage tells it to run the function depending on the value of the key, resulting in the page to constantly reload. Is there anyway to store the value of the key without it reloading constantly?

Comment: that's good you figured it out, update the question with those code snippets which is causing this cyclic nature. otherwise it's hard to guess what is exact issue.

Comment: @JoshSpires, first of all your code should be like this ``` window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
     const value = localStorage.getItem("saved");
    if (value == "0") {
        commercial();
    } else if (value == "1") {
        consumer()
    } else {
       reset()
    }
});```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's much cleaner, thanks. Would I maybe need to create separate functions to get the key values, rather than using the same one for everything?

Comment: not required. anyways it working fine or still it's reloading?

Comment: Still reloading

Comment: It's strange, as long as URL is same(previous and new) it shouldn't reload. any change in URLs after reload? post that generated URL too.

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: Just noticed that when I onclick the reset function the reloading stops, so there's an issue with consumer and commercial functions.The only difference is that reset uses localStorage.removeItem where the other two uses localStorage.setItem

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with using `{{ collection.handle }}`. Would it be better to get `{{ collection.handle }}` using a variable?

Comment: I guess that's correct because there it'll not match with final generated URL, `/collections/dji/commercial` to `/collections/{{ collection.handle }}/commercial`. so it'll redirect again

Comment: if that's the case, you need to figure out why do you need to handle that on load. if it's required we may need to restrict to specific paths only.

Comment: The website stocks products from 81 brands, so I can get the exact URLs for each one and use them instead?